# Can you use OpenSSL to generate an md5 or sha hash on a directory of files?

Tags: hashing, md5, openssl

I'm interested in storing an indicator of file / directory integrity between two archived copies of directories.  It's around 1TB of data stored recursively on hard drives.  Is there a way using OpenSSL to generate a single hash for all the files that can be used as a comparison between two copies of the data, or at a later point to verify the data has not changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could recursively generate all the hashes, concatenate the hashes into a single file, then generate a hash of that file.

Comment: For a single command, something like `md5 -q <(find . -type f 2>/dev/null | xargs md5 -q | sort)` works well in Bash and doesn't require a temp file. Alter if your system uses `md5sum` instead of `md5`. Also be aware that `sort` can behave differently on different platforms which will affect the final checksum if the order is different. Add flags like `! -name ".DS_Store"` to the find component to ignore certain files, like the .DS_Store files on Mac OS X that can throw off the checksum since they're generated by the OS.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do a cumulative hash of them all to make a single hash, but you can compress them first then compute the hash:

```
$tar -czpf archive1.tar.gz folder1/
$tar -czpf archive2.tar.gz folder2/
$openssl md5 archive1.tar.gz archive2.tar.gz
```

---

to recursively hash each file:

```
$find . -type f -exec openssl md5 {} +
```

Comment: 1TB of data - no room to tar them. Is there a way to recursively generate hashes of all files?

Comment: yes, added it to my answer.

Comment: nice tar idea, but not always applicable. the 'find' method is better in general. if there is 'no room' for the tarball: 

% tar -cf - folder | openssl md5

Answer (score 2):

Doing a md5 sum on the tar would never work unless all of the metadata (creation date, etc.) was identical as well, because tar stores that as part of its archive.

I would probably do an md5 sum of the contents of all of the files:

```
find folder1 -type f | sort | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 cat | openssl md5
find folder2 -type f | sort | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 cat | openssl md5
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be probably interested to output the digest in coreutils format (identical to md5sum -b)

So md5sum command could be :

```
find . -path '*/.svn' -prune -o -type f -print0 | sort | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 openssl dgst -md5 -r
```

or with an output to a file

```
find . -path '*/.svn' -prune -o -type f -print0 | sort | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 openssl dgst -md5 -r > ../mydigest.md5
```

Answer (score 2):

It's better to list a hash for each file, and check each hash. If you make a hash from all files, and one of them becomes corrupt, you won't know which one is corrupt. But if you list hashes for every file, a script can tell you when any hash doesn't match (which will tell you that a file is corrupt or changed).

Also, recursive hashing with `find` is simpler than so much piping:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 openssl dgst -sha256 -r >> hashes.sha256
```

You'll want to append the output via `>>`, because xargs will invoke `openssl` several times, *but only as often as it needs* to process all files (not e.g. one invocation per file). `-r` is for coreutils hash file syntax. You don't want to use OpenSSL's `-out` with `xargs`, as it will overwrite the file on each invocation. Additionally you may want to capture STDERR, in case OpenSSL can't read/open some files: `2>> error.log`

If storage isn't a bottleneck then you can use the `-P n` argument of `xargs` to run several OpenSSL processes in parallel (not recommended for hard drives).

note: GNU coreutils (md5sum etc.) use OpenSSL as the library for hashing. But you may still want to use OpenSSL instead if your coreutils are very outdated: Support for H/W [SHA-hash acceleration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54277666) was only added recently to OpenSSL. SHA1/SHA256 can be faster than MD5 without acceleration, and are definitely in the gigabit/s range with it.